# CSS - Resuming normal document flow after absolute positioning an element

Tags: html, css

I have a div in my site that has absolute positioning but want to resume the normal document flow after it. Is there anything like `clear:both;` for this or will I need to create a hidden element with the same height to get the same effect.

So as you can seehere the 2nd Div is being hidden behind the absolute positioned element.

```css
div{
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:20px;
}
#div_1{
  position:absolute;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#F00;
}
#div_2{
  height:100px;
  background-color:#0F0;
}
```

```html
<div id="div_1">Div that should appear on top</div>
<div id="div_2">Div that should appear below</div>
```

I need that element to stay absolute positioning but want to achieve the same doc flow as this:

```css
div{
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:20px;
}
#div_1{
  height:50px;
  background-color:#F00;
}
#div_2{
  height:100px;
  background-color:#0F0;
}
```

```html
<div id="div_1">Div that should appear on top</div>
<div id="div_2">Div that should appear below</div>
```

Comment: you could try adding padding-top to the parent div with same height as the pos absolute div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once an absolutely positioned element is out of the document flow, there is no way of putting it back in.

Your suggestion to add in a hidden element is viable, but you can also set the `margin-top` of your second div to equal the height of the absolutely positioned element - which would place it below the first div.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm trying to make it as responsive as possible so rather than setting a margin I thought I might be able to create a hidden element and use JS to set the height to the same as the other element as it might resize

Comment: @PaddyHallihan hmm, in this case simply make the margin top the same as height, no? ... why bothering with another hidden element?

Comment: @TemaniAfif the height of the element isn't fixed it's responsive so it has different heights

Comment: @PaddyHallihan read what you said : you want to add a hidden element and use JS to match its height with the absolute element ---> in this case use JS to match the margin-top with the height, easier

Comment: @TemaniAfif That still won't work for me as everything is being generated with php so not even sure what the next element would be to give the margin to.